# Probability Distribution Formula of Selling the Cars Which Have Airbag

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A Company wants to sell $50$% of its cars which have Airbags.  What is the formula of probability distribution of the number of the cars which have airbags in the next $4$ cars that the company is going to sell?

Note : My problem is that i don't know how selling $50$% of the cars is related to the next cars which company is going to sell. Also, in this question we don't know how many cars the company has in total. So that's why i'm stuck on it.

Comment: As it stands, there really isn't much to work on.  What the company "wants to sell" hasn't got any obvious connection to anything.  Perhaps they simply want you to assume that each sale  is the toss of a fair coin (probability $\frac 12$ that any given sale includes airbags).  But that's a stretch.

Comment: A company that wants to sell 50% of its cars is aiming too low.

Comment: So, of the cars in the lot with airbags, the Company wants to sell 50% of them? Can you clarify a little.

Comment: @lulu if we assume the way you did, can u write the answer please ? :)

Comment: @turkeyhundt yes :) that's correct

Comment: For what it's worth, I interpret the question to mean that the company would prefer that $50\%$ of the cars it sells include airbags.  But it really is poorly worded and ambiguous.  Have you reprinted it exactly as it appears, with no alterations?

Comment: Under my (crude) interpretation, let $p_n$ be the probability that exactly $n$ of the cars sold have airbags.  then $p_n=\binom 4n\times \frac 1{16}$, for $0≤n≤4$.

Comment: @lulu yes what i wrote is exactly what the question says ... i know it's somehow strange but that's why i'm stuck on it

Comment: If that's the case, I feel like we don' have enough info. If there are 100 Airbag cars and 2 without, the answer will be different then if there are 50 of each.